# Upgrade Spring 2.5 version to support Spring Expression

Tags: spring, spring2.x, spring-2.5

I am using Spring 2.5.1 version. I am unable to upgrade my version to higher due to management feedback including heavy end to end testing requirements. Is there a workaround I can top up Spring 2.5.1 with Spring Expression features may be adding Spring Expression jar?

I need to refer property of another bean which does not support in Spring 2.5.1 version. Below addresslookup is another bean and url is its property. How do I gain this feature in Spring 2.5.1 without upgrade to Spring version?

```
 <jaxws:endpoint id="serviceEndpoint"
    implementor="#automationService" publishedEndpointUrl="#{addressLookup.url}" />
```

Comment: not an answer to your question, but nonetheless: you know that 2.5 is outdated and no longer receives security updates ? Even 3.2 will we EOLed  in the foreseeable future (https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/15/spring-framework-3-2-x-eol-on-dec-31-2016), so an update to 4.1 is recommended

Comment: Unfortunately , this is a legacy big system. Client does not like to upgrade at this point. Thanks

Comment: You cannot nor should you ever try to mix different versions of jars from a framework, that will bite you at some point.